# Google App Engine TaskOptions

Tags: google-app-engine

Trying to learn from Google's tutorial on Queues and Backends:
http://googcloudlabs.appspot.com/codelabexercise8.html

The part I don't understand is this, specifically the TaskOptions methods of param("xml", data) and header("Host", backend blah blah). What is the first and second argument for in param()? In header, how do I specifically point to instance #2 (if I have 5 of those setup) of the "order-backend"?

```
// Create Task and push it into Task Queue 
Queue queue = QueueFactory.getQueue("OrderQueue"); 
Queue queue = QueueFactory.getQueue("OrderQueue"); 
TaskOptions taskOptions = TaskOptions.Builder.withUrl("/createOrder") 
param("xml", data) 
.header("Host", BackendServiceFactory.getBackendService().getBackendAddress("order-backend")) 
.method(Method.POST); 
queue.add(taskOptions);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you have a HTML form.

```
<form action="/createOrder" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="xml" value="$(data)" />
</form>
```

Think of the first argument to param() as the name for a form input element, and the second argument as the value for that input element.

Just as a single form often has a number of input elements with different names and values, TaskOptions are often assembled by calling param() a number of times with different arguments.